# What functional purpose does a cortical column serve?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neural-network

The [Blue Brain project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Brain_Project) led by Henry Markram focused on simulating [cortical columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_column) under the idea they form basic processing units of the brain/cognitive function.

**What functional purpose does a cortical column serve?**

I am looking for (synapses) of mathematical, conceptual, & scientific models. What is a leading theory, what is the evidence for it, etc?

Comment: [Vernon Mountcastle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernon_Benjamin_Mountcastle) was instrumental in the discovery of the cortical column.  I will elaborate a bit more later, but some of his older papers are probably freely available online.

Comment: How about starting with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_column ?

Comment: @H.Muster I was actually going to make the same comment, but I was surprised by how uninformative that wikipedia article and the [discussion here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Brain_Project#Neocortical_column_modelling) were. In general, a quick Google search doesn't reveal an obvious definitive resource, either. Hence, it might be good to provide a canonical answer here if jonsca has time. Of course, I do wish that the OP would focus the question more, since it is pretty vague.

Comment: Here's an example of a [much better focused question on bio.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1074/500).

Comment: the other question seems to be focused on mere _anatomy_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with the theory that the column is the binary unit involved in all cortical processing and memory for many years. Articles are available at [my profile page (Robert Moss) at researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Robert_Moss2) and academia.com. The first article was [published in 2006](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255969149_Of_bits_and_logic_Cortical_columns_in_learning_and_memory._The_Journal_of_Mind_and_Behavior_27_215-246?ev=prf_pub) with [an update in 2012](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236145789_A_Theory_of_Hemispheric_Specialization_Based_on_Cortical_Columns?ev=prf_pub). I have published several non-peer-reviewed, more easily understandable articles that are also posted at those sites. [One major paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262932793_The_Role_of_Dynamic_Columns_in_Explaining_Gamma-band_Synchronization_and_NMDA_Receptors_in_Cognitive_Functions) has been recently published that explains the possible microcircuitry of dynamically formed columns.

Comment: thx can you post a ref for a single survey article to start with

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on CogSci.SE. Would you mind providing quick summaries of the evidence and conclusions of the papers you link to?

Comment: I don't believe a link to one researcher's largely not peer reviewed and certainly not largely accepted answer does not constitute a proper answer.