# Is there knowledge of the receptive field patterns of cortical columns in associative brain regions?

Tags: neuroscience, perception, neurophysiology, sensation, sensory-perception

The retinotopic, area-based connectivity patterns of the columnar receptive fields in the visual cortex are well-established.

**Do any mappings of the columnar receptive field connectivity patterns exist for associative brain regions?**

Comment: Some useful related questions to help improve your own:
- https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5735/4397
- https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/42293/5427

Comment: following @Seanny123 's lead, I landed on a [2016 article by Robert Moss](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307476361_A_Theory_on_the_Singular_Function_of_the_Hippocampus_Facilitating_the_Binding_of_New_Circuits_of_Cortical_Columns) which seems to be a promising intro to the topic for my interests. I don't feel confident creating an actual answer based on this however, so I'll just leave this here as a footnote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**
Associative brain areas are not retinotopically organized. Only lower visual areas more upstream from these areas are organized in such a predictable, low-level way. Higher up, things get complicated and unpredictable.

**Background**
[Visual **receptive fields**](http://hubel.med.harvard.edu/book/b10.htm) and [retinotopy](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e180/lectures/v1/node3.html) are generally **well-preserved in the periphery and subcortical areas** (*e.g.* in the [retina](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-i-foundations/simple-anatomy-of-the-retina/), [optic nerve](https://www.msdmanuals.com/home/eye-disorders/optic-nerve-disorders/overview-of-optic-nerve-disorders) and the [LGN in the brainstem](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/courses/perception/lecturenotes/V1/lgn-V1.html)) and lower cortical areas (*e.g.*, [V1](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/courses/perception/lecturenotes/V1/lgn-V1.html) and [V2](http://www.lifesci.sussex.ac.uk/home/George_Mather/Linked%20Pages/Physiol/Cortex.html)) (*e.g.*, [Palmer & Rosenquist (1974)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006899374902959)). Typically, receptive fields are **larger and less well-defined in [higher visual areas](http://www.lifesci.sussex.ac.uk/home/George_Mather/Linked%20Pages/Physiol/Cortex.html)** and are virtually absent in the [associative cortices](http://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/Ch12.S1.html), where complex associations within and between modalities are made (*e.g.*, [Smith *et al*. (2011)](https://academic.oup.com/cercor/article/11/12/1182/492324/Estimating-Receptive-Field-Size-from-fMRI-Data-in)).

Consider the [ventral stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-streams_hypothesis) in the visual pathway as an example (Fig. 1). Here, the [primary visual cortex (V1)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11524/) shows simple representations of the retinal image with retinotopicity. However, along the way to the associative cortices, cells become responsive to progressively more complicated structures, including specific faces.

[image: ventral stream]
<sup>Fig. 1. The ventral ('what') stream of the visual system. source: [Kaiser & Haselhuhn (2017)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZ6d.jpg)</sup>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Kaiser and Haselhuhn, *J Neurosci* (2017); **37**(8): 1965-7](http://hubel.med.harvard.edu/book/b10.htm)

**-** [Palmer & Rosenquist, *Brain Res* (1974); **67**(1): 27-42](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006899374902959)

**-** [Smith *et al*., *Cerebral Cortex* (2011); **11**(12): 1182–90](https://academic.oup.com/cercor/article/11/12/1182/492324/Estimating-Receptive-Field-Size-from-fMRI-Data-in)</sub>

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the concept of a cortical column is a bit controversial in higher order cortical areas. Personally I don't mind to use the columnar terminology to refer to organization within depth of cortex, and obviously nearby neurons still share connectivity and function in higher-order cortex, but the abrupt feature shifts observed in lower-order cortex are absent.